# Mysterious error message when using iftex package

Tags: conditionals

I am using `iftex` package to detect which TeX engine I am using. In the following example (MWE) I am using pdfTeX engine:

```
\documentclass[norsk]{beamer}
\usepackage{iftex}
%\RequireLuaTeX  
\ifXeTeX
   { % XeLaTeX
    \usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage[]{norsk}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage[]{unicode-math} 
    }
\else \ifPDFTeX   {
    % default: pdfLaTeX
    \usepackage{babel}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    %\usepackage{lmodern}
    %\usepackage[adobe-utopia]{mathdesign}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    %\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}
    }
\else  \ifLuaTeX   {
    %LuaLaTeX
    \usepackage{babel}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage[]{unicode-math}  
    }  
   \fi
\fi  

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}
  Some text $34$.
\end{document}
```

This gives the following mysterious error:

ERROR: Undefined control sequence

--- TeX said ---
--- HELP ---
No help available

(but a PDF is generated) I have tried many variants of the above!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two problems:

1. You are using three conditionals but have only two closing `\fi`'s.
2. Use of the conditionals should be performed in the traditional way:

   ```
   \if..
     <true>
   \else
     <false>
   \fi
   ```

   Note there is not grouping of the `<true>` and/or `<false>` clause. That's the main problem in your case, as definitions are then made local to that group (and don't survive), cause control sequences to be undefined.

Here is your minimal example with the updated conditionals:

```
\documentclass[norsk]{beamer}
\usepackage{iftex}
%\RequireLuaTeX  
\ifXeTeX
  % XeLaTeX
  \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setmainlanguage[]{norsk}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \usepackage[]{unicode-math} 
\else \ifPDFTeX   
  % default: pdfLaTeX
  \usepackage{babel}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  %\usepackage{lmodern}
  %\usepackage[adobe-utopia]{mathdesign}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  %\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}
\else \ifLuaTeX
  %LuaLaTeX
  \usepackage{babel}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \usepackage[]{unicode-math}  
\fi\fi\fi

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}
  Some text $34$.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The syntax is wrong: you're probably used to C or something like that. TeX conditionals are always in the format

```
\if<name><test>
  <true text>
\else
  <false text>
\fi
```

with no braces around the two cases. Well, braces can be used, but they will group the tokens inside them, which usually is not wanted. In general loading a package inside braces is wrong.

You can simplify your input by observing that if you're using neither XeTeX nor LuaTeX, then you'll be using PDFTeX (well, there's also `pTeX` or `upTeX`, but that's for Japanese and is not covered by `iftex`).

Notice also that making a document that runs under all three engines is only a dream, but for simple documents you can probably get away.

```
\documentclass[norsk]{beamer}
\usepackage{iftex}

\ifXeTeX
  \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setmainlanguage[]{norsk}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \usepackage[]{unicode-math} 
\else
  \ifLuaTeX
    \usepackage{babel}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage[]{unicode-math}  
  \else
    % only pdftex remains
    \usepackage{babel}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    %\usepackage{lmodern}
    %\usepackage[adobe-utopia]{mathdesign}
    %\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}
  \fi
\fi
```

Instead of `iftex` you can load `ifxetex` and `ifluatex`:

```
\documentclass[norsk]{beamer}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}

\ifxetex
  \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setmainlanguage[]{norsk}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \usepackage[]{unicode-math} 
\else
  \ifluatex
    \usepackage{babel}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage[]{unicode-math}  
  \else
    % only pdftex remains
    \usepackage{babel}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    %\usepackage{lmodern}
    %\usepackage[adobe-utopia]{mathdesign}
    %\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}
  \fi
\fi
```

When in the final part (relative to `pdftex`), you can also use `\ifpdf` (provided by the `ifpdf` package) to do something special in case `latex` is used.

A different implementation with `expl3`:

```
\documentclass[norsk]{beamer}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\enginecode}{m}
 {
  \tl_gset:Nn \g_kjetil_engine_tl { pdftex }
  \xetex_if_engine:T { \tl_gset:Nn \g_kjetil_engine_tl { xetex } }
  \luatex_if_engine:T { \tl_gset:Nn \g_kjetil_engine_tl { luatex } }
  \str_case:Vn \g_kjetil_engine_tl { #1 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nn { Vn }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\enginecode{
 {xetex}{
   \usepackage{polyglossia}
   \setmainlanguage[]{norsk}
   \usepackage{fontspec}
   \usepackage[]{unicode-math}
 }
 {luatex}{
    \usepackage{babel}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage[]{unicode-math}
 }
 {pdftex}{
    \usepackage{babel}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    %\usepackage{lmodern}
    %\usepackage[adobe-utopia]{mathdesign}
    %\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}
 }
}
```

The syntax (which might perhaps be improved) is

```
\enginecode{%
  {xetex}{<code if the engine is XeTeX>}%
  {luatex}{<code if the engine is LuaTeX>}%
  {pdftex}{<code if the engine is pdfTeX>}%
}
```

None of the pairs is mandatory. Remember to protect the end-of-line if the command is used in the body of the document.

Comment: "Notice also that making a document that runs under all three engines is only a dream, but for simple documents you can probably get away."  Thanks for this. Yes, but mo pint is having a header/preamble which makes it easier to experiment without changing to much in the file.

Comment: can this code expanded to used for PlasTeX / htLaTeX and pure LaTeX?

Comment: @PeterEbelsberger I don't know about PlasTeX; for `htlatex` I believe that the LaTeX3 team could provide a conditional, but I'm not sure. It's more a new question, though.